# Adding a second CustomerLocation in Acumatica via REST API

Tags: rest, acumatica

For many of our customers we have additional addresses that they used over the years. We would like to add them as additional CustomerLocations. I don't seem to be able to this however and nothing turns up in google search. I'm using Postman and do a PUT on the CustomerLocation endpoint. Here is the request body

```
{
        "CustomerID": {"value": "<CUSTOMER_ID"},
        "LocationID": {"value": "SECONDARY"}, 
        "LocationName": {"value": "Secondary"},
        "AddressOverride": {"value": "True"},

        "Contact": {
                "Address": <address data follows>
```

The exception says "Object Reference not set to an instance of an object."
Has anybody done this before?

Answer (score 0):

Try using "Customer" instead of "CustomerID", thats the name of the field. The inconsistency is maddening, I know